# jQuery.offset() sets position: absolute. I need position: fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you set an element's offset with `jQuery.offset({coords})` it also sets the CSS property `position` to `absolute`.

I have a div, however, that I set to `position: fixed` in my CSS, and I want it to remain that way, even after setting the offset of the element with jQuery.

Now, I'm sure I can probably set the offset, then set `position: fixed` again, but I was wondering if there is a way I can tell jQuery to set the position to fixed instead of absolute when it sets offset.

**HTML**

```
<div class="searchResults">
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
DIV.searchResults {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 501;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("DIV.searchResults").offset({left: 0, top: 0});
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<div class="searchResults" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
    ...
</div>
```

Obviously, since jQuery is setting the position in the style, it will trump the value of my CSS class. So I need a way to tell jQuery to set `position` to `fixed` instead of `absolute`, or tell it to set the offset without setting the value of the CSS property `position`.

Comment: Did you try: '$("DIV.searchResults").css({left: 0, top: 0});' would simply set left and top, position would be unchanged?

Comment: Is that all that `$.offset()` does? I assumed it did more than that.

Comment: $.offset can get or set, documentation says: "The .offset() setter method allows us to reposition an element. The element's position is specified relative to the document", which changes the position (from static to relative, or - as it seems - from fixed to absolute). So the css for top / left is all you need in your case.

Comment: Submit an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I commented above, in your case all you need is to modify the CSS for top and left like this:

```
$("DIV.searchResults").css({left: 0, top: 0});
```

Because the $.offset setter method only manipulates the left, top and position values to make the element relative to the page (from static to relative, and from fixed to absolute). Since you want it position fixed, set the values directly.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not that elegant, but I think you can just chain `.css()` after that to be sure that `position` is set to `fixed` like this:

jquery

```
$("DIV.searchResults").offset({
    left: 0, 
    top: 0
}).css("position" : "fixed");
```

Not tested, but I think that'll work.